# rpm specs to work on redhat7 and redhat8 servers

Tags: rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I want to build a RPM that will work on rhel7 and rhel8. It is a python program.
I encountered a couple of issues I am not able to track.
on redhat8 there is no un-versioned python packages

per instance in rhel7 the python packages are like this:

```
python-jinja2
```

whereas in redhat8 they are named like this:

```
python3-jinja2
```

how to add conditional flags to rpm that calls the correct dependencies based on the distribution version?

I understand that the redhat version can be obtained by a macro `%{rhel}` Is this the right way to do it?

```
%if 0%{?rhel} <= 7
### Dependencies ###
Requires: python python-jinja2 python-markupsafe python-sqlalchemy
### Build Dependencies ###
BuildRequires: python-setuptools
%else 
Requires: python3 python3-jinja2 python3-markupsafe python3-sqlalchemy
BuildRequires: python3-setuptools
%endif
```

then I have the macro `%{__python} that gives errors on rhel8

```
%build
%{__python} setup.py build

%install
%{__python} setup.py install --skip-build --root $RPM_BUILD_ROOT

error: attempt to use unversioned python, define %__python to /usr/bin/python2 or /usr/bin/python3 explicitly
```

how can I best make a single specs file that works on both versions as we have an environment running both versions?